# Sort by price, quantity low-> high

Tags: php, database

I read so many questions/answers on stack overflow but no one give the answer which I want to require.

[image]

Here is the my result query. I have required result of sort by price low-> high but it gives me a result that starts with records that have the price 0. This is correct, but I don't want the 0 price records first. Result should start with prices greater than 0 and 0 price records should be displayed last.
Please help me to solve my this query.

> For example, the result should start start with price 125.0, 125.0 ... 0, 0

Comment: what's the query you have so far?

Comment: @Marius, I have done following query
SELECT product_id, quantity, price
FROM `product`
ORDER BY `product`.`price` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: I have required attached file result (This image was edited by mspaint) [link](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/0465y30iba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
    product_id, quantity, price, 
    CASE price WHEN 0 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
    as is_price_zero
FROM
    product
ORDER BY
    is_price_zero ASC,
    price ASC
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_price_zero FROM product ORDER BY ' at line 4

Comment: There are some syntex error near  CASE price = 0.

Comment: @VipulJethva  attach sql file for table data here .

Comment: @VipulJethva. Sorry for that. I've updated the query. give it an other try

Comment: @Marius It's working brother. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think you need all the Price accending products first and than the products with 0 price

So you can run a query to get your data without 0 price values

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE price > 0
ORDER BY  price ASC LIMIT 0 , 30) as first_query
```

Than run a query to get data of 0 price values

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE price = 0
```

and than union so final query will be

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE price > 0
ORDER BY  price ASC LIMIT 0 , 30) as first_query UNION SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE price = 0
```

Just change your field name as per your requirements.

Comment: Sourabh, I know this query. I don't want without 0 record. 
I have required attached file result (This image was edited by mspaint) [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ad5y32j8f)

Comment: @VipulJethva I have edited the answer please check if this is what you want.